# on selecting single checkbox or click on all or clear button I am not able to select checkbox and update state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, state-management

In this react component on selecting single checkbox or click on all or clear button I am not able to select checkbox and update state. I tried very hard but still not working if someone can please me with this?

I have defined the array group function which i am passing as a prop

const groups = [
{
name: "Group 1",
options: [
{ label: "Option 1", selected: false },
{ label: "Option 2", selected: false },
{ label: "Option 3", selected: false }
]
},
{
name: "Group 2",
options: [
{ label: "Option 4", selected: false },
{ label: "Option 5", selected: false },
{ label: "Option 6", selected: false }
]
}
];

import React, { useState } from "react";

```
const MultiSelectDropdown = ({ groups, onSelectAll, onClear }) => {
         const [groupData, setGroupData] = useState(groups);
         const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = useState([]);
    
         const handleOptionSelect = (groupIndex, optionIndex, groupData) => {
         const updatedOptions = groupData[groupIndex].options;
          
         groupData[groupIndex].options.map(function(elem,index ) {
            console.log(elem.label , updatedOptions[optionIndex].label, 2111);
          if (elem.label === updatedOptions[optionIndex].label) { 
              elem.selected = true;      
          }
          // console.log(18, groupData)
        });
        console.log(21, groupData)
        setGroupData(groupData);
      }; 
      console.log(22, groupData);
   
      
      
      
    
      const handleSelectAll = (groupIndex) => {
        const updatedOptions = [...selectedOptions];
        updatedOptions[groupIndex] = updatedOptions[groupIndex].map((option) => ({
          ...option,
          selected: true
        }));
        console.log(23, updatedOptions)
        setSelectedOptions(updatedOptions);
        onSelectAll(groupIndex);
      };
    
      const handleClear = (groupIndex) => {
        const updatedOptions = [...selectedOptions];
        updatedOptions[groupIndex] = updatedOptions[groupIndex].map((option) => ({
          ...option,
          selected: false
        }));
        setSelectedOptions(updatedOptions);
        onClear(groupIndex);
      };
    
      return (
        <div>
           {groupData && groupData.map((group, groupIndex) => (
            // console.log(group, groupIndex)
            <div key={groupIndex}>
              <h3>{group.name}</h3>
              <button onClick={() => handleSelectAll(groupIndex)}>All</button>
              <button onClick={() => handleClear(groupIndex)}>Clear</button>
              {group && group.options.map((option, optionIndex) => (
                <label key={optionIndex}>
                  <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    checked={option.selected ? true : false} 
                    onChange={() => handleOptionSelect(groupIndex, optionIndex, groupData)}
                  />
                  {option.label}
                </label>
              ))}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default MultiSelectDropdown;
```